# Fixing an error while querying for existing an data

Tags: linq, many-to-many

I am trying to determine if a variable already exists, so I won't create a duplicate. But I keep getting an error:

**Cannot convert from System.Linq.IQueryable**

Here's the code that results in the error:

```
public List<QuestionTag> ParseTags(string tags)
{
    var tagList = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    var questionTags = new List<QuestionTag>();
    var anyNewTags = false;

foreach (var tag in tagList)
{
    var tagExists = _context.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tag);
    if (tagExists == null)
    {
        var newTag = new QuestionTag() { Tag = new Tag() { Name = tag } };
        _context.QuestionTags.Add(newTag);
        questionTags.Add(newTag);

        anyNewTags = true;
    }
    else
    {
        questionTags.Add(tagExists); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    }

}
if (anyNewTags) _context.SaveChanges();
return questionTags;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagExists query hasn't yielded a result yet, hence the error. In order to make it yield, use either .ToList(), First() or FirstOrDefault().

Assuming it results in a list, then use:

```
questionTags.AddRange(tagExists.ToList());
```

Assuming it results in a single object, then use:

```
questionTags.Add(tagExists.First());
```

====== Edit =======

Your questionTags is of type `List<QuestionTag>`, but when you add `tagExists`, this is of type `Tags`.

So change this,

```
var tagExists = _context.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tag).Select(x => new QuestionTag { Tag = new Tag { Name = x.Name} }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: None of that worked. It still returns the same error.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I appreciate it. Just one little error left:
var tagExists = _context.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tag).Select(new QuestionTag { Tag = new Tag { Name = **x.Name**} }).FirstOrDefault();
**The name x does not exist in the current context**

Comment: Oops forgot to add `x =>` in Select. Updated now.

Comment: If I could give you a million likes, I would. Thanks with all my heart.

Comment: Mark it as answer then? If it helped, you can upvote also.